# Dealing with URLs and query strings

Tags: .net, url, uri

Is there a class in the .NET runtime that will allow me to deal with query strings easily.

I would like the following functions:

- add a query parameter to a URL (it may or may not already have one in the base url)
- convert a parameter value to a "safe" URL parameter.
- convert a parameter from a "safe" URL parameter back to a normal one.

Is there a class that handles this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .NET Base Class Library doesn't offer anything for dealing with Query Strings, it just treats them as a generic Name Value Collection.  Your best bet is to either write your own extensions methods or find some on the web.  For example: http://www.charlesrcook.com/archive/2008/07/23/c-extension-methods-for-asp.net-query-string-operations.aspx

Code from CharlesRCook.com:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string WriteLocalPathWithQuery(
        this NameValueCollection collection, Uri Url)
    {
        if (collection.Count == 0)
            return Url.LocalPath;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(Url.LocalPath);
        sb.Append("?");

        for (int i = 0; i < collection.Keys.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i != 0)
                sb.Append("&");
            sb.Append(
                String.Format("{0}={1}",
                collection.Keys[i], collection[i])
            );
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static NameValueCollection ChangeField(this NameValueCollection collection,
        string Key, string Value)
    {
        return ChangeField(collection, Key, Value, true);
    }

    public static NameValueCollection ChangeField(this NameValueCollection collection,
        string Key, string Value, bool Allow)
    {
        if (Allow)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(collection[Key]))
                collection[Key] = Value;
            else
                collection.Add(Key, Value);
        }

        else //remove the value all together
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(collection[Key]))
                collection.Remove(Key);
        }
        return collection;
    }

    public static NameValueCollection Duplicate(this NameValueCollection source)
    {
        NameValueCollection collection = new NameValueCollection();
        foreach (string key in source)
            collection.Add(key, source[key]);
        return collection;
    }
}
```